# Using Mono Development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hi there I'm new to coding and I created a C# file directly from unity and used the code for my main menu in college on visual studio

```
Public void onclick(int level){
Application.LoadlLevel(level);
}
```

But I have a Mac so I got Mono Development and now I don't know how to do it. I use the same method to add a C# file but now it doesn't work or more specifically I don't know how to do it. I searched tutorials on youtube and other websites but can't find. Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: proably not answering your question, but it's `public`, not `Public` .

Comment: also, how it "doesn't work" ? Do you have any error in console ? what message ? Can you show the full class / namespace ?  (you can't just declare a function in a `.cs` C# file, in Unity or not, it has to be part of a class block, which has to be in a namespace block). it doesn't do what you want ? If so, what are you expecting ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is the least suitable place for "new to coding" guys, as you should look for tutorials and "how-to" series or books on such topics to learn the very basic, before posting a moderate question about a technique.